# Best way to implement wordwrap for items in DropDownList items ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I currently have an ASP.NET DropDownList with a set width. When I click the DropDownList the list that pops up has a list of items with varying lengths of text. As is, the list when it pops up automatically expands the width to fit the length of the longest item on the list.

What I need to happen is to set the width of the list that pops to be restricted by a maximum width. Then, if an item on the list is longer than this width, wrap the text to the next line.

I need to know if this is even possible with the ASP.NET DropDownList control, and if it isn't what other options do I have as far as implementing some sort of other control.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" style="width:150px;" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="Test" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="LONG TEXT SAMPLE EXAMPLE OF LONG TEXT ENTRY TEST TEST TEST TEST" Value="Test"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="Test"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The sample I am looking at is above.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas at all?